# Laravel updateOrInsert with 'OR' or 'AND' operator in first arguments?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

While it is possible to have multiple arguments for the `updateOrInsert` in Laravel query builder and what is the operator used by default.
For example in the documentation it is mentioned:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->updateOrInsert(
        ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
        ['votes' => '2']
    );
```

Does that mean that email `&&` name are checked or does it mean email `||` name is checked? How can we control it for one or the other if required?

Please forgive me if this is a silly question or if it is not worded as per the correct vocabulary, as I am new to Laravel. I couldn't find this information in the documentation or API.

Comment: Yes, you can use `updateOrCreate` too, `updateOrCreate` is an eloquent method, while `updateOrInsert` is a query builder method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updateOrInsert()** method is used to update an existing record in the database if matching the **condition** or create if no matching record exists. Its return type is *Boolean*.

**Syntax** :

```
DB::table('blogs')->updateOrInsert(
   [Conditions],
   [fields with value]
);
```

In your query :

```
DB::table('users')->updateOrInsert(
   ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
   ['votes' => '2']
);
```

It will check if `email == 'john@example.com'` & `name == 'john'`, then it will update `votes=2`.

Comment: But what if I want `email == 'john@example.com'` or `name == 'john'`?

Comment: Bad luck. I don't find **OR** method for `updateOrInsert` query builder in the  official  github repo of Laravel. Take a look https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bc31b3b22c44fcc797ad4e5a6f95f5bccdd63acc/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2699